# MySQL query to limit the number of categories

Tags: mysql

I have a query to display posts by category. I need to display result of only first 5 categories. My query displays categories and count of categories. The query display all categories and number of posts in each category.

I want to limit the display of categories.

I have this query:

```
SELECT qp_category, name, count(qp_category) as Total
FROM questionpapers
INNER JOIN
questioncategory
ON
questionpapers.qp_category = questioncategory.qcid
GROUP BY qp_category;
```

This is the table structure I have

```
category table
--------------------------
qcid | name | active
--------------------------

post table
--------------------------------------------------------
qpid | title | qp_category | description | date | active
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: how about adding `Limit 5` in end of your query??


`SELECT qp_category, name, count(qp_category) as Total
FROM questionpapers
INNER JOIN
questioncategory
ON
questionpapers.qp_category = questioncategory.qcid
GROUP BY qp_category LIMIT 5;`

Comment: Yes it is working  by adding the LIMIT 5.

Comment: glad it helped and sad that I didnt post this as an answer but posted in comment. lol

Comment: need a accept comment as answer feature in stackoverflow

Comment: will you accept my answer if i post it as an answer below?

Comment: yes i can accept

Comment: I answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add "LIMIT" in end of your query

```
  SELECT qp_category, name, count(qp_category) as Total 
FROM questionpapers
 INNER JOIN questioncategory ON questionpapers.qp_category = questioncategory.qcid 
GROUP BY qp_category LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is the LIMIT:

```
SELECT qp_category, name, count(qp_category) as Total
FROM questionpapers
INNER JOIN
questioncategory
ON
questionpapers.qp_category = questioncategory.qcid
GROUP BY qp_category
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: And same comment as above

Answer (score 0):

LIMIT should help.

```
SELECT qp_category, name, count(qp_category) as Total
FROM questionpapers
INNER JOIN questioncategory ON questionpapers.qp_category = questioncategory.qcid
GROUP BY qp_category
LIMIT 5;
```

`FYI`: If `SQL Server` then use `TOP` and if `MySQL` or `PostgreSQL` then use `LIMIT`.

Comment: Likewise, note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: Couldn't agree more but there is no mention on ordering the categories. If sequence is not required then having ORDER BY clause is overhead.

Comment: Not really. If someone wants the top 5 of something, then ORDER BY is required, even where a GROUP BY clause is provided. The manual covers this in more detail

Comment: My intention is not to argue but I can give you tons of real life example where you do not care about sorted data when using GROUP BY and/or LIMIT. On same note, some database flavor like MySQL sorts data automatically by the columns in GROUP BY clause and order by is not required. In fact it is recommended that if you want to avoid sorting overhead then use ORDER BY NULL.

Comment: That erroneous perception is EXACTLY what the manual discusses in more detail